# Issue with curl check cpanel authentication

Tags: php, curl, cpanel

I create a function to check cpanel.

`(input : host,link,password)`

`(output: return true if valid or false if invalid)`

This function works perfectly on localhost.

The issues come when I upload my script on web hosting. It doesn't work.

It's the same version of PHP 5.6 on my localhost & web host.

```
function cpanel_check($host,$user,$pass,$timeout=5){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( curl_errno($ch) == 0 ){
        curl_close($ch);
        return 1;
    }else{
        curl_close($ch);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does the PHP on the webhosting service throw any errors? Or will the function proceed and return something?

Comment: always return false

Comment: That means, the code gets to the line `return 0;` ? Can you run this code: `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());exit;` and put the output of this into your question?